# Find files matching a pattern, replace strings and then diff the output with original, command fails

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal, diff

I am trying to find files with the name.* and run sed on the ones that match, then pipe to diff to see what was changed.

However the command fails. If I remove the pipe an diff it is happy to output results. Why is failing with the diff? Is there a better way to do this?

```
> find -type f -name "names.*" -printf '%p' -exec sed 's/Cow/Kitten' {} | diff {} - \;
diff: extra operand ';'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
find: missing argument to \-exec\'`
```

Answer (score 0):

A shell is needed to do what you wanted, like so.

```
find -type f -name "names.*" -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    sed 's/Cow/Kitten/' "$f" | diff "$f" -
done' _ {} \;
```

---

In-one-line

```
find -type f -name "names.*" -exec sh -c 'for f; do sed 's/Cow/Kitten/' "$f" | diff "$f" -; done' _ {} \;
```

---

- See [understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

---

Or using a `while` + `read` loop and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do
  sed 's/Cow/Kitten/' "$files" | diff "$files" -
done < <(find -type f -name "names.*" -print0)
```

---

The latter script is white space/tab/newlines safe but is strictly `bash` as oppose to the former script which is POSIX `sh`. (Will/should work/execute with any POSIX compliant shell.)

- See [How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)
- See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)