# Searching for a file in a directory of gziped tar files

Tags: bash, search, find, tar

OK, I have a directory where I backup my dev server every hour.  I work a great many projects at the same time and I use GIT and at times uncommitted files are deleted when I go from branch to branch.  I am sure I could avoid this with some neat GIT trickery or simply slowing down to read what GIT is about to do, but we are on year 36 of coding and year 12 of using GIT and sometimes my fat, old fingers just want to start over.  It doesn't happen often but it happens.

So here is my directory

```
Backup_09_15_2021-20:00.tar.gz
Backup_09_15_2021-21:00.tar.gz
Backup_09_15_2021-22:00.tar.gz
Backup_09_15_2021-23:00.tar.gz
...
```

Each of these is about 2G and contains hundreds of thousands of files each.  I retain several days of files so there might be 70-120 of these files in the directory

What I need to do is find a file by name, pretty simple

So for example, today I was missing a file called *createPackageCommand.php*.  I need to see all the files that have a file by that name and print out the info so I can see file sizes and dates.

My current bash command looks like this

`find . -name "Backup_*.tar.gz" -exec bash -c 'echo {};tar -ztvf {} | grep CreatePackageCommand' \;`

It outputs something like this

```
./Backup_09_20_2021-16:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_19_2021-15:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_22_2021-17:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_17_2021-11:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_21_2021-10:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_16_2021-17:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_23_2021-11:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_17_2021-08:00.tar.gz
./Backup_09_21_2021-16:00.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  0 kbrill staff     2874 Sep 21 11:12 var/www/crm/custom/src/Console/Command/CreatePackageCommand.php
```

So it prints out each tar files name and if there is a matching file in it then we get the greps output for that.

Its slow, ugly and I can't live without it.

2 questions

1. Is there a better way to search these files?
2. Is there a way to make the command search the files in order.  Newest to oldest?

Comment: More or less the same question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69292091/find-files-matching-a-pattern-replace-strings-and-then-diff-the-output-with-ori/69292806#69292806

Comment: `find . -name "Backup_*.tar.gz" -print0 | sort -nz` With GNU/BSD `find`

Comment: And GNU `sort` afaik.

Comment: I'd think about setting up something where every time a new backup is created, the involved files are added to a sqlite database (And removed when an old one is deleted), so you can query it instead of a bunch of compressed tarballs, which aren't the most friendly to such tasks.

Comment: Re 1: tar --list (akak -t) accepts a member but it's whatever (relative) path so probably too painful to use.  You could create `tar tvf $f.tar > $f.txt` (plaintext or compressed) as part of your backup so you wouldn't have to search through the whole .tar file just for the name.  ripgrep will speed up your search.  Another option would be a index (search engine) like xapian.  Also, seriously. look into backup tool called borg.

Comment: I have no idea why the thought of having a text file with all the names never occurred to me. That's the perfect solution.  Thanks